# Why I am not able to set the color of element containing class top using Javascript as shown below?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">surprise</div>
    <script>
        document.getElementsByClassName("top").style.color ="red";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't know why this is not working, hoping to have a good explanation .

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return a nodelist, as its plural. You could use `querySelector` instead

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements. You want `getElementsByClassName('top')[0]` or `querySelector('.top')`. You should also get in the habit of adding `console.log` calls to parts of your code to help debug the return values from functions.

Comment: Since it returns a collection of elements (get**Elements**ByClassName), you'll have to mention the index of element you want to access.
`getElementsByClassName('top')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access style property on element. `document.getElementsByClassName("top")` will return you an `HTMLCollection`.

you need to update your script:

`document.getElementsByClassName("top")[0].style.color ="red";`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">surprise</div>
    <script>
        document.getElementsByClassName("top")[0].style.color ="red";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```